# Using tastypie resource in view

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Im using the resource in my view. Whenever there are errors, they will be returned in immediatehttpresponse and its a httpbadrequest object. When I do r.response I could see the contents which is in xml form, but I couldnt retreive the status code. How to handle the errro response?

```
except ImmediateHttpResponse, r:
    print r.response
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of HttpBadRequest the status code is always 400 (tastypie.http at line 41):

```
class HttpBadRequest(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 400
```

Also:

```
r.status_code
```

should give it to you.

Comment: except ImmediateHttpResponse, r:
       response= HttpResponse(r.response)
       s = response.status_code
       c = response.content To identity all the possible response, I have to check on how many status codes to make sure handle all?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Please try to be more specific. There is an error in your syntax though - r = HttpResponse(r.response) should be response = HttpResponse(r.response). Altough this probably won't give you what you expect... Also ImmediateHttpResponse is a HttpResponse already.

Comment: And actually I think you should ask another question. The one you asked has been answered and the discussion should not take place in comments... So perhaps choose the answer, and ask a separate question ?